# R ggplot: align axis and facet labels to same height

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a plot using `ggplot2` package. I want to have the labels of the facets and the first axis label per facet on the same height. (ie B and 1, and C and 7 in this example, on one line)

Now 1 and 7 are slightly below B and C.

[image]

Is there a solution, other than dropping the facets and making custom axis labels? I want to retain the facets for lay-out purposes.

This is the reproducible example code:

```
tst <- structure(list(cat = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
                      value = c("", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), 
                      estimate = c(-0.0426199922176837, -0.107596434933479, 
                                   0.128745430017863, 0.139050280246278, 0.083438545558878, 0.0353561915958545, 
                                   0.546763649283651, -0.149906486541816, -0.0127866090227199), 
                      lo = c(-0.0463977305439748, -0.13825456791009, 0.0431405496176399, 
                             0.0510334567045194, 0.0149123471502507, -0.0170404544157982, 
                             0.495233535388663, -0.220062569612812, -0.0648067498492498), 
                      hi = c(-0.0388422538913925, -0.0769383019568673, 0.214350310418086, 
                             0.227067103788036, 0.151964743967505, 0.0877528376075072, 
                             0.598293763178639, -0.0797504034708195, 0.03923353180381)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data=tst,
       aes(x = value,y = as.numeric(estimate), ymin = lo, ymax = hi )) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab('') + ylab("Effect size (95% Confidence Interval)") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lo, ymax=hi)) + 
  facet_grid(cat~.,
             scales = "free_y",
             space = "free_y",
             switch = "y"
  ) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(hjust=0,vjust = 1,angle=180,face="bold"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.spacing = unit(-0.5, "lines"),
        strip.background = element_blank()) +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see only a way to make custom axis labels, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
tst %>% 
 mutate(id = ifelse(value < 7 & cat == "C", "", cat)) %>% 
 mutate(id = factor(id, level=c("A", "B", "C", ""))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = value,y = as.numeric(estimate), ymin = lo, ymax = hi )) +
 geom_point() +
  facet_grid(id~.,
             scales = "free_y",
             space = "free_y",
             switch = "y") +
 xlab('') + ylab("Effect size (95% Confidence Interval)") +
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lo, ymax=hi)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle=180, face="bold"),
        panel.spacing = unit(-0.5, "lines"),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: In this case an additional facet is introduced (id = ""). If applied to a longer dataset (i.e  add cat D with 3 values), cat C and D with value >1 will be merged into one facet. But I guess I have to abandon the facetting all together and make a custom axis.

Comment: I ended up using `facet_grid(cat+value~.)` with a custom labeller function for both variables.

Comment: @Wietze314 Nice, please consider to show your solution as well.